# struggling to set a background image in HTML emails for all mail programs

Tags: html, css, email

I am trying to set a  background image in an HTML email which needs to viewed in programs such as webmail and gmail aswell.

I have read other tutorials and the general rule is it is not recommended, I used the background in the body tag and as a failover have the same background image used in table tag, as some programs strip away the body and head tage from the emails.

Is there a way to successfully carry a background over web based programs and on a phone such as samsung?

HTML

```
<body topmargin="10" leftmargin="0" bottomargin="20" background="images/background.jpg">

<!--first table contains failover background-->

<table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td background="images/background.jpg">
<center>
<table style="border: #FFF 4px solid;" width="600px" cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0">
<tr name="link-1">
<td align="center" valign="top">
<font style="font-family: Century Gothic,CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif;font-size:12px; color:#FFF;">CLICK HERE TO VIEW IN BROWSER</font>
</td>
</tr>

<!--THE REST OF THE MAIL THAT WORKS-->

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: It's worth noting email client support for using background-image in HTML emails. As you can see on the following link, they are not supported in Outlook 2007/10/13+, and outlook.com      https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Hi I am trying to keep it simple, as much as I want to use CSS, I have stayed away from it because of the simplicity needed for these HTML EMAILS. is it possible to have a background in an email over GMAIL and WEB BASED mail programs, that is where the problem is arising displaying in GMAIL etc. and on Samsung phone email.

Answer (score 2):

If you have problem with using background-image in outlook, you should use VML

```
<v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
style='width:500px;height:500px;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:-1;' 
src="yourImageUrl" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get it working for multiple devices is using the following website: https://backgrounds.cm which will help with Outlook.

Now-a-days this is less of an issue, but I would suggest you ensure your image is the full URL and publically available not based on your local machine.